# The elements of a matrix group with order two and its centre

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrix-equations, normal-subgroups

Let $$ G=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}
    \bar{a} & \bar{b} \\
    \bar{0} & \bar{c}
  \end{bmatrix} \text{with $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{c}$ in $\mathbb{F}^{*}_{7}$ and $\bar{b}$ in $\mathbb{F}_{7}$}\right\}. $$

I have to do two things. Determine the elements of $G$ which have order $2$ and compute the centre of $Z(G)$ of $G$.

First the elements with order $2$. I think I need to find elements such that the matrix times itself equals the matrix with identity elements as coefficients. That is we need $$\begin{bmatrix}
    \bar{a} & \bar{b} \\
    \bar{0} & \bar{c}
  \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
    \bar{a} & \bar{b} \\
    \bar{0} & \bar{c}
  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \bar{a}\bar{a} & \bar{a}\bar{b}+\bar{b}\bar{c} \\
    \bar{0} & \bar{c}\bar{c}
  \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
    \bar{1} & \bar{0} \\
    \bar{0} & \bar{1}
  \end{bmatrix}$$

Thus $\bar{a}\bar{a}=\bar{c}\bar{c}=1$ which is only the case for $\bar{a},\bar{c}=\{\bar{1},\bar{6}\}$. This leaves us with four possibilities. Namely, $(\bar{a}=1, \bar{c}=1)$,$(\bar{a}=1, \bar{c}=6)$,$(\bar{a}=6, \bar{c}=1)$ and $(\bar{a}=6, \bar{c}=6)$. Now for $\bar{b}$ this implies $\bar{a}\bar{b}+\bar{b}\bar{c}=\bar{b}(\bar{a}+\bar{c})=\bar{b}=\bar{0}$ for all $b \in \mathbb{F}_{7}$.

Now about the centre $Z(G)$. I know that for the centre subgroup the following holds:
$Z(G)=\{z \in Z \mid zgz^{-1}=g \text{ for all } g \in G\}.$ I have absolutely no idea how to proceed so any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: since the group is abelian then has trivial center

Comment: Valid point Shaun, I edited it.  @janmarqz trivial centre being all entries with identity elemtents? Thus $\bar{a}=\bar{c}={1}$ and $\bar{b}=\bar{0}$.

Comment: @janmarqz That makes no sense. If the group is Abelian it is its own center. On the other hand if it's non-Abelian it does not necessarily have a trivial center.

Comment: @Mathbeginner $\bar a^2 = 1$ has $\bar a = 1$ as another solution. So you already have four possible $(\bar a, \bar c)$ pairs with $\bar a^2 = \bar c^2 = 1$.

Comment: What about $\bar{a} = 1$, $\bar{c} = 6$, and $\bar{b} \in \mathbb{F}_7$ or $\bar{a} = 6$, $\bar{c} = 1$, and $\bar{b} \in \mathbb{F}_7$?

Comment: @M.Vinay: of course you are right. That makes indeed four options. This also has implications for $\bar{b}$ since now it has to be computed for each of the four options. I'd suggest for $\bar{a}=\bar{c}=1 \Rightarrow 2\bar{b}=\bar{0} \Rightarrow \bar{b}=\bar{5}$ and likewise for the other option, resulting in $\bar{b}=\bar{0}$.

Comment: @Hyperion $\bar{b}$ must be defined explicitly right? It depends on those $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{c}$ values but it does not hold for just any $b \in \mathbb{F}_{7}$ I'd say.

Comment: Well $\bar{a} = \bar{1}$ and $\bar{c} = \bar{6}$ implies that $\bar{a}\bar{b}+\bar{b}\bar{c} = \bar{b}(\bar{a}+\bar{c}) = \bar{0}$, regardless of $\bar{b}$. Likewise, the flipside follows.

Comment: @Hyperion that makes sense. I will edit the initial work I had with this information.

Comment: Sometimes more generality makes things easier, and certainly the question would be easier replacing $F_7$ with an arbitrary field of characteristic not $2$.

Comment: @Mathbeginner I mean trivial as $G=Z(G)$, but I was wrong. point.